# Proving that set is either finite or countable

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $f$ be an arbitrary function, which maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Prove that the set of points of strict local minimum of $f$ is either countable or finite.

I tried to create some bijection mappings, but all my attempts were unsuccessful.

Maybe we somehow can split the domain of our fuction on disjoint intervals, so that on every such interval contains at most one point of strict local minimum and then we can create a bijection between our intervals and $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Your idea works (ignore the disjoint). Just try it out (hint: strict local minimum means you have a neighborhood around your minimum which contains a rational number). EDIT: Neighborhoods in $\mathbb R$ are open intervals.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587683/are-strict-local-minima-of-a-general-function-always-countable

Comment: @ctst, you run into problems because these intervals need not be disjoint.

Comment: @MeesdeVries They certainly aren't disjoint (since they are an open covering), but you can find rational numbers between two minima with them :-) (after looking at Roberts links: same idea...)

Comment: One nice approach is to use the [Lindelöf property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space)

Comment: @ctst So basically what you are saying is I can create mapping $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to  \mathbb{R}$, which maps $(a, b) \mapsto p$, where $p$ is some point of strict local minimum and $(a, b)$ are the closest rational numbers from lefthand and righthand of $p$?

Comment: @FalsePromise Nearly. Don't take $a,b$ as the closest rationals (this doesn't work) but as any rationals left- and righthand of $p$ in a neighborhood of $p$ where it is strict minimal. In Roberts link this is explained really good.